# Do the categories of Sets and Smooth manifolds with smooth functions have zero morphisms. And how are compositions with the empty set defined?

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds

When reading [wiki zero morphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism) it seems that the category of sets does not have zero morphisms. Also, I could not find how the composition with the empty map works in the Set. Can someone explain that?

Edit: there is a confusion about what 'does have zero morphisms' mean. Here I actually mean: 'category with zero morphisms'.

Comment: That is not particularly enligthening. Do you know how $f \circ \emptyset$ and $ \emptyset \circ f$ are defined?

Comment: There is some confusion here. A category can have some zero morphisms and still not be a "category with zero morphisms." In Sets, the (only) function $h:\emptyset\to S,$ for any $S,$ is a zero morphism, since there is only one morphism with $\emptyset$ as a co-domain. But Sets is not a "category with zero morphisms," because that expression zero morphisms for all pairs $X,Y..$

Comment: "Have all zero morphisms" is also not actually a terminology. The wikipedia page has two things: (1) A definition of what a zero morphism is, and (2) a definition of a category being a "category with zero morphisms." Terminology is important.

Comment: In sets: Since when $X\neq \emptyset$ and $Y=\emptyset,$ there are no maps $X\to Y,$ so there can't be a zero morphism $0_{XY}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some categories have initial and final object isomorphic (call it $0/1.$) Then for any objects $X,Y,$ you have a unique $o_{XY}:X\to 0/1\to Y$ which you can show is a zero-morphism and it satisfies the requirement to be a category "with zero morphisms."

This class contains the typical examples of categories with zero morphisms:

- Groups, R-modules, Vector spaces over a fixed field
- Pointed sets, pointed topological spaces

In Sets, if $X\neq\emptyset$ and $Y=\emptyset,$ there is no map $X\to Y,$ so there are not enough maps for Sets to be a "category with zero morphisms."

I think you can show that any map in Smooth manifolds fails to qualify as a zero-morphism. Basically, if $h:M_1\to M_2$ with $M_1$ non-empty, then we can choose some pair $f,g:M_2\to M_3$ so that $f,g$ are not equal on the image of $h$ in $M_2.$

For example, if the category includes disconnected manifolds, we can take $M_3=M_2\sqcup M_2$ and $f,g$ the two natural maps $M_2\to M_2\sqcup M_2.$
It might be a little harder if the category consisted only of connected manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Andrews has answered your main question about zero morphisms, so I'll just answer the question "how are compositions with the empty set defined?"

In the category of sets, a function $X\to Y$ is a set $f\subseteq X\times Y$ such that for all $x\in X$, there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$. From this definition, we see that $\emptyset \subseteq X\times Y$ is a function $X\to Y$ if and only if $X = \emptyset$. Indeed, if $X\neq \emptyset$, then picking some $x\in X$, there is no $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in \emptyset$, so $\emptyset$ is not a function $X\to Y$. On the other hand, if $X = \emptyset$, then $\emptyset$ satisfies the definition of a function $X\to Y$ vacuously.

Now how do we compose with the empty function? Well, let's view $\emptyset$ as a function $\emptyset \to Y$, and suppose we have a function $g\colon Y\to Z$. Composing, we should get a function $(g\circ \emptyset)\colon \emptyset \to Z$. You should expect to get $(g\circ \emptyset) = \emptyset$, since the empty function is the only function with domain $\emptyset$. And indeed, we have $$(g\circ \emptyset) = \{(x,z)\mid \exists y\, (x,y)\in \emptyset\text{ and }(y,z)\in g\} = \emptyset.$$

On the other hand, let's view $\emptyset$ as a function $\emptyset \to Y$, and suppose we have a function $g\colon Z\to \emptyset$. Composing, we should get a function $(\emptyset\circ g)\colon Z\to Y$. Again, we have $$(\emptyset\circ g) = \{(z,y)\mid \exists x\, (z,x)\in g\text{ and }(x,y)\in \emptyset\} = \emptyset.$$
In fact, in this case we must have $Z = \emptyset$ and $g = \emptyset$, since there are no functions from non-empty sets to the empty set.